# questão sobre banco de dados

Tags: mysql

Listar somente os nomes dos clientes que realizaram mais do que 10 aluguéis de carro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comecei banco de dados faz pouco tempo, se puderem me dar essa força eu agradeço.

criei da seguinte forma:

```
select Nome, count(CodAlu) as qte
From Cliente
WHERE CodAlu in ( select CodAlu from Aluga where (CodAlu> 10))
```

está certo?

Comment: Não repita perguntas. Se quiser acrescentar mais detalhes é só editar a pergunta e acrescenta-los, não precisa uma nova pergunta para isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cláusula HAVING é usada para especificar condições de filtragem em grupos de registros ou agregações.
É frequentemente usada em conjunto com a cláusula GROUP BY para filtrar as colunas agrupadas.

```
SELECT c.CodCli, c.Nome, Count(*) qte
  FROM Cliente c INNER JOIN Aluga a ON ( c.CodCli = a.CodCli )
 GROUP BY c.CodCli, c.Nome
HAVING Count(*) > 10
```